# add constant after keyword

Tags: vim, sed, awk, grep

I have a question concerning the manipulation of a text file.
I have something like this

```
any text keyword 21 any text 32 any text
any text keyword 12 any text keyword 12 any text 23 any text
any text keyword 34 any text (keyword 45) any text (34) any text
```

now I wonder if I can grep/awk/sed/vi/.. somehow to add constants after the keyword?
For example I want to add e. g. a value of 10 to every integer after keyword but leaving the other numbers and the file format the same?

```
any text keyword 31 any text 32 any text
any text keyword 22 any text keyword 22 any text 23 any text
any text keyword 44 any text (keyword 55) any text (34) any text
```

Sorry, I did not find anything so far...

Comment: What should be done on some broken input like `keyword NAN`?

Comment: I just got this suggestion, 
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) if ($i=="keyword") {++i; $i += 10 }; print}'  thanks a lot for this one, it worked right away, is it now also possible to exclude one pattern, such as 'do not replace keyword 34'?

Comment: @Christoph: Instead of `$i += 10`, you could do `if ($i!=34) { $i += 10 }`.

Answer (score 3):

If Perl solution is ok for you:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=keyword )(\d+)/$1+10/ge;' file
```

Comment: thank you so much! is it possible to exclude one pattern such as 'do not replace keyword 34'?

Comment: You want both `-p` and `-n`?

Answer (score 1):

you mentioned **vim**, here it goes:

```
:%s/\v(keyword )@<=[0-9]+/\=submatch(0)+10/g
```

Comment: thank you so much! is it possible to exclude one pattern such as 'do not replace keyword 34'?

Answer (score 1):

I tried *hard* for a `sed` version:

```
sed 's/keyword[ \t]*\([0-9]*\)/keyword $(( \1 + 10))/g;
     s/"/\\"/g;
     s/^/echo \"/;
     s/$/\"/' input | 
  sh
```

Comment: Nice trick; that was really hard work. Don't you need to escape existing `$`, too (and maybe some more characters like the backtick?)

Answer (score 0):

This works.  Now I will admit I'm no awk expert so there may be shorter ways to do it but this is what I hacked together:

```
#!/bin/sh

cat $1 | awk \
'function incr(str) {
    if (match(str, "[0-9]+")) {
        number = substr(str, RSTART, RLENGTH)
        number = number+10
        printf("keyword %d",number)
        str = substr(str, RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
}
function findall(str, re) {
    where=match(str, re)

    if (where==0)
    {
      print(str)
    }
    else
    {
      printf("%s", substr(str, 0, RSTART-1))
      offset=RSTART+RLENGTH
      incr(substr(str, RSTART, RLENGTH))
      str = substr(str, offset)
      findall(str, re)
    }
}
{
    findall($0, "keyword [0-9]+");
}'
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to check whether "keyword" is before the number.

Comment: Ah, I didn't read the original question close enough.  I will try to modify the answer.

Comment: Edited it to incorporate requirement for 'keyword'.  I'm sure an awk expert would laugh.  I found this question really helpful for me to go through the exercise so I'm glad for the original question posted.

Answer (score 0):

look at this perl solution

```
perl -pe 's/keyword (\d)+/"keyword ".($1 + 10)/eg' your_file
```

if you wanna exclude some number from the sum (34 and 35 in this example)

```
perl -pe 's/keyword (\d)+/if ($1 != 34 && $1 != 35) { "keyword ".($1 + 10) } else { "keyword ".$1 }/eg' your_file
```